# how do I link to a servlet within javascript code

Tags: java, excel, servlets, xls

I got an XLS pic inside of an HTML link, and i need to verify some information first before calling to the servlet, that's why i'm not including the servlet inside of the href="". So i've created a javascript function that verifies the input information in order to be used by the servlet.

(The Servlet returns a XLS in order to be saved by the user).

Tried this:

```
document.location.href = 'saveExcelServlet.do?' + <<GET method attributes>>;
```

But it didn't work.
It says:
Problem accessing /wscall-metrics-web/saveExcelServlet.do. Reason:

```
null
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

If i write  it works...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

M.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance the URL isn't quite built the way you expect. A great poorman's technique for debugging this kind of thing is to assign a variable and pop it up in an alert:

```
var newLoc = 'saveExcelServlet.do?' + <<GET method attributes>>;
alert(newLoc);
```

You can see exactly what URL is getting fetched.

Comment: Yeah, i've solved it! Sorry for bother you guys!! It was my fault... i made I mistake inside of the Servlet, that's why it wasn't showing the things correctly! Going to delete the question.